# iPhoneX Error - This app was not installed from the App Store and must be reinstalled manually

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-x, reinstall, enterprise-distribution

My application is signed with **Enterprise distribution certificate**. When I try to install my app on iPhone X it installs successfully but when I try to open, it gives me an error `"This app was not installed from the App Store and must be reinstalled manually"`

Please note that app is opening and working on all other devices. This issue occurs only some specific iPhone X, not on every iPhone X.

Can someone please tell me why I am facing this error.

Screenshot is attached
[image]

Comment: Probably you'r using production certificate and installing the app by external source i mean except app store.

Comment: @dahiya_boy No, I am using enterprise certificate.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I just got the same error.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 2):

The app may have been offloaded. Offloading is a new iOS 11 feature that allows user or the iOS system to remove an app to free up space without deleting any of its configurations or settings.

To know if an app has been offloaded, it displays a small cloud icon in front of its name.

When opening an offloaded app, Apple tries to download the app back from App Store. Since it's an enterprise app that's not available on App Store, it can't download it and shows up this error.

The solution? Well, just what Apple says: "This app was not installed from the App Store and must be reinstalled manually". Download the enterprise app again from where it's hosted and install it.

Comment: But if this app was created by me, and i am trying to install it from my own computer? that is, the app is not found at the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this post doing a Google search, here was the fix for our scenario:

This issue usually revolves around a desperate Apple ID and Pin. The first step will be to recover your Apple ID device PIN. This is accomplished by following these steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Tap [Your Name] > Password & Security > Change Password
3. If you are logged in to iCloud and have a passcode enabled, you will be prompted to enter the passcode for your device
4. Follow the onscreen steps to update your password

This should reassociate the Apple ID with the Pin, and allow the app to install.